Shifting values from one cell to another when data is added to the table
I have two tables in Excel, one named "Calendar" and the other named "PlanTable".
The left table is Calendar, the right is PlanTable.

I am trying to calculate how much should each worker do depending on the plan for a certain machine on that date.
Example:
Let's say we take 1-Jul-2024. In the right table on that day the machines (under the "Utilaj" column) R1, R3 and R9 worked, beside each of them is the plan for the day (under the "Plan" column).
After that we check the right table for how many workers were assigned to the R1, R3 thus R9 machines.
After finding out that on 1-Jul-2024 there were 2 workers for R1, 1 for R3 and 3 for R9.
The values beside each of the workers should be the (plan of the machine/count of workers that worked at it on the certain date).
I succeeded in making this, but when I put a new person in the "Calendar" table, the values don't move with the workers.
Code for "Calculeaza Fapt" the fourth button.
Sub Refresh()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim planTbl As ListObject
    Dim calendarTbl As ListObject
    Dim selectedDate As String
    Dim utilaj As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim workerCount As Long
    Dim planValue As Double
    Dim faptValue As Double
    Dim workerDict As Object
    Dim utilajKey As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set planTbl = ws.ListObjects("PlanTable")
    Set calendarTbl = ws.ListObjects("Calendar")

    ' Initialize dictionary to count workers
    Set workerDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Loop through the dates in the PlanTable
    For Each r In planTbl.ListColumns("Data").DataBodyRange
        selectedDate = Format(r.Value, "dd-mmm-yy")
        Debug.Print "Processing date: " & selectedDate
        
        ' Reset workerDict for each date
        workerDict.RemoveAll
        
        ' Count the number of workers for each Utilaj on the selected date from the Calendar table
        For Each cell In calendarTbl.ListColumns("Data").DataBodyRange
            If Format(cell.Value, "dd-mmm-yy") = selectedDate Then
                utilaj = cell.Offset(0, calendarTbl.ListColumns("Utilaj").Index - calendarTbl.ListColumns("Data").Index).Value
                If workerDict.exists(utilaj) Then
                    workerDict(utilaj) = workerDict(utilaj) + 1
                Else
                    workerDict.Add utilaj, 1
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Debugging output
        For Each utilajKey In workerDict.Keys
            Debug.Print "Utilaj: " & utilajKey & ", Workers: " & workerDict(utilajKey)
        Next utilajKey
        
        ' Divide the Plan value by the number of workers and assign to the Fapt column in the Calendar table
        utilaj = r.Offset(0, planTbl.ListColumns("Utilaj").Index - planTbl.ListColumns("Data").Index).Value
        planValue = r.Offset(0, planTbl.ListColumns("Plan").Index - planTbl.ListColumns("Data").Index).Value

        If workerDict.exists(utilaj) Then
            workerCount = workerDict(utilaj)
            faptValue = planValue / workerCount

            ' Update the Calendar table
            For Each cell In calendarTbl.ListColumns("Data").DataBodyRange
                If Format(cell.Value, "dd-mmm-yy") = selectedDate And _
                   cell.Offset(0, calendarTbl.ListColumns("Utilaj").Index - calendarTbl.ListColumns("Data").Index).Value = utilaj Then
                    cell.Offset(0, calendarTbl.ListColumns("Plan").Index - calendarTbl.ListColumns("Data").Index).Value = faptValue
                End If
            Next cell

            Debug.Print "Assigned Fapt value: " & faptValue & " to Utilaj: " & utilaj
        Else
            Debug.Print "No workers found for Utilaj: " & utilaj & " on date: " & selectedDate
        End If
    Next r

    MsgBox "Values updated successfully!"

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub


If I understand the question correctly I don't think you need VBA for this.

The formula in column E is:
=XLOOKUP(1,([@Data]=PlanTable[Data])*([@Utilaj]=PlanTable[Utilaj]),PlanTable[Plan])/COUNTIFS([Data],[@Data],[Utilaj],[@Utilaj])

